# How can I extract unnamed keys from a nested json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am really lost here. Please help me understand how I can extract specific objects (without a key) from nested json list.

Here is the structure of the json list:

```
"data":{
    "result":{
           "person":
            [
             [
            {
               "personName":
                "jobs":
              [
                             {
                              "employerName":
                              },
                              {      
                              "employerName":
                               }
                ]
                         },
                         {
                           "siteName": 
                             ...
                         }  
                       ]
                      ]
                  }
    }
```

I have two array variables declared like so in my state container

```
PersonObject: Array<Person>,
JobsObject : Array<Jobs>
```

In my function, if I do this :

```
const res = //calls api
store.setState({PersonObject: res.body.data.result.person})
```

This will store the whole object in PersonObject

B**ut I want to assign "person" object and its values to PersonObject and "jobs" to JobsObject. But there is no key assigned to the person.**

When I try to look up the key's value by doing so

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(res);

//I get this as output
0: "0"
1: "length"
```

Comment: Looks like wrong JSON structure. Objects key->value can't be without value.

Comment: And please add proper object, now it is not valid

Comment: One can access object properties like `someObject["someProperty"]`. Arrays prefer to use implied keys that are integers in a sequence starting at 0 so the first item in an array would be `someArray[0]`. Because of this, you probably want `res.body.data.result.person[0].jobs`.